# Проблема с url и views. django

Tags: python, django, apache

Есть urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
...,
url(r'^reviews/', views.reviews),
url(r'^reviews/page(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.reviews), 
]
```

И есть view.py

```
def reviews(request, page):
    ...
```

Apache почему то выдает ошибку:

```
reviews() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page',
```

но аргумент присутствует во view.py.

Если в url.py изменить

```
url(r'^reviews/page(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.reviews),
```

на

```
url(r'^reviews/page(?P<page_1>\d+)/$', views.reviews),
```

и перезаустить apache, ошибка будет та же, хотя, как мне кажется он уже должен показывать такую ошибку

```
reviews() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page_1'
```

Если в view.py добавить значение по умолчанию

```
def reviews(request, page=1):
    ...
```

То, ошибка исчезает, но вне зависимости от url, page будет всегда равен значению по умолчанию.

Кто-нибудь может обьяснить, что происходит? django 1.9, apache 2.4.

Comment: Поменять r'^reviews/' на r'^reviews/$'? Регулярки жадные и вторая строчка никогда не будет обработана - все эти запросы будут считаться для первой регулярки.

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо. Как можно было забыть про конец строки.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
def reviews(request, page=None):
    if page:
        ...
```